# Mysql sum of column by week and divided sum value of the last week

Tags: mysql

In my database, data is stored by day. I want to sum the value by week and then divided the value by the sum value of the last week. Is it possible achieved by SQL?
Example :

```
   Table  Structure
   ItemCode   Amount         DatebyDay
   01         500           20170815
   01         500           20170816
   ...
   01         500           20170819
   01         1000           20170821
   01         1000           20170822
   ...
   01         1000           20170825
    ...
   02         2000           20170815
   02         2000           20170816
   ...
   02         2000           20170819
   02         3000           20170821
   02         3000           20170822
   ...
   02         3000           20170825
   ....
```

My expected result is:

```
 01  2                //(1000*5)/(500*5)
 02  1.5              //(3000*5)/(2000*5)
```

So any one have any idea how do do this.Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate more details about your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ITEMCODE,F_VAL FROM 
(
    SELECT @PREV_VAL,CASE WHEN ITEMCODE=@PREV_ITEMCODE THEN AMT/@PREV_VAL END F_VAL, @PREV_VAL:=AMT,ITEMCODE,@PREV_ITEMCODE :=ITEMCODE FROM
    (
        SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AMT,DATEBYDAY,ITEMCODE FROM 
        (
            SELECT *,WEEK(DATEBYDAY) WEEK 
            FROM STRUCTURE,(SELECT @PREV_VAL:=0,@PREV_ITEMCODE :=0)Z1 ORDER BY ITEMCODE, WEEK(DATEBYDAY)
        )Z GROUP BY ITEMCODE,WEEK
    )Y 
)X WHERE F_VAL IS NOT NULL;
```

**You can check using [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/452f37/1)  Using below query**

You can try above code.

Here i had used two variable for calculating your business logic.

Definitely it will help you.

Comment: If this answer isn't sufficient, consider uploading your tables/data to sqlfiddle.com (using mysqldump for example) and then reply to this comment so I/we can help more.

Comment: I was actually making that suggestion to the OP, not to you, but what problem are you experiencing? sqlfiddle.com should provide helpful error messages.

Comment: sqlfiddle.com appears to be sick, try https://www.db-fiddle.com/ instead

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question, but I'd start with creating a temporary table like:

`SELECT SUM(amount), WEEK(DatebyDay) AS week FROM Structure GROUP BY week;`

You can then join it to a copy of itself where `t1.week = t2.week-1` or similar.